# How interchangeable are the adjectives in the comparative “the closer/nearer, the …”?

Tags: differences, comparatives, adverbials

In an allusion to Dave Starr’s magnificent¹ cover art,
I had the opportunity to use its title idiomatically, and said:

> *“The closer the bone, the sweeter the meat.”*
> … and was promptly corrected: *“Nearer.”*
> That kept me wondering:

**In what semantic instances do we have to specifically use ‘closer’ *or* ‘nearer’ respectively?**

For [‘near’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/near#Adjective) as well as [‘close’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close#Adjective), there are plenty of non-specific and/or interchangeable uses (e.g. “a near/close friend”, “stay near/close”), but also definite distinctions (e.g. “close/near quarters”). Consequently at least, we could say *“We’re close to/near the bone”*, couldn’t we?

There is also [a question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38468/difference-between-close-and-near) asking about differences of the adjectives themselves, which I couldn’t apply to the construct in question (adverbial comparative with ‘the’)—it’s all about physical distance.

Curiously, [the digram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+closer+the%2Cthe+nearer+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20closer%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20nearer%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20closer%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20nearer%20the%3B%2Cc0) suggestes a transition in frequency by 1947, lacking explanation of course.

*¹(For the actual cover art, see [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Dave-Starr-The-Nearer-The-Bone-The-Sweeter-The-Meat/release/4885939) or [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B5IOOGM).)*

Comment: I don’t find “a close friend” and “a near friend” equivalent. A near friend sounds like someone who is almost a friend, but not quite or not yet.

Comment: 'Near' and 'near to' are often interchangeable, and are often interchangeable with 'close to',  but you can't say 'I'm close London / home / the motorway / the bone'. If anything, 'The closer the bone' means 'the nearer the bone is to me / us / you / a person', not 'the closer to the bone [the meat you're serving] is located'. 'The closer the tyrannosaur, the more you wish you'd brought a bigger gun.'